# error while showing image from server into viewPager android with picasso

Tags: android

I am trying to slide image in `viewPager`, images sliding well automatically while I am using images from drawable folder. But while I am tying to show images from server to be slided from server image url its showing error something like this:

> The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!

I have tried to solve this problem by googling but I could not solve that. I need help. My code is below:

**activity work:**

```
String imageListQuery=null;

try {
    imageListQuery=URLEncoder.encode("getChatRooms", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("getChatRooms", "UTF-8");

    backgroundTask=new AsyncTaskClass(context_NavigationActivity, new AsyncTaskResult() {
        @Override
        public void AsyncTaskResult(String result) throws JSONException {

            if(result!=null){
                pageViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            JSONObject js = new JSONObject(result);
//            Log.v("ResDFrJ",js.toString());
            JSONArray arr = js.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject tmpOb = new JSONObject(arr.optString(i));
                UsersListShowClass tmpClass = new UsersListShowClass();

                tmpClass.setProPicUrl_users(InfoSetClass.getBaseUrl()+tmpOb.getString("profile_pic_id"));
                imageList.add(i,tmpClass);

            }
        }
    });

    backgroundTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"POST","mobileApi/chatRooms",imageListQuery);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

viewPager=(ViewPagerCustomDuration)findViewById(R.id.pageViewerId);
viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(15);
pageViewerAdapter=new PageViewerAdapter(context_NavigationActivity,imageList);

NUM_PAGES=pageViewerAdapter.getCount();
viewPager.setAdapter(pageViewerAdapter);
pageViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
            currentPage = 0;
        }

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
    }
};

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(update);
    }
}, 100, 5000);
```

**adapter:**

```
public class PageViewerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<UsersListShowClass> imageList;
    UsersListShowClass usersListShowClass;

    public PageViewerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<UsersListShowClass> imageList){
        this.context=context;
        this.imageList=imageList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(imageList != null){
            return imageList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page_viewer_adapter_layout,container,false);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.videoViewId);
        usersListShowClass=imageList.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context).load(usersListShowClass.getProPicUrl_users()).error(R.drawable.ic_circle_24dp).
                placeholder(R.drawable.ic_circle_24dp).into(imageView);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PageViewerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

i know its already solved almost similar error in stackoverflow, but in my case maybe a little different. please need help.

Comment: Why are you calling `ViewPager` a pageViewer?

Comment: sorry i have call it mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
pageViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after:

```
imageList.add(i,tmpClass);
```

Comment: thanks it's working ,but one more help need after adding this auto sliding stopping while its reached to last image .how to sliding it to reverse also